# listing directory contents with xargs and grep

Tags: grep, ls, xargs

I have a directory with lots of json and pdf files that are named in a pattern. I am trying to filter the files on name with the following pattern `\d{11}-\d\.(?:json|pdf)` in the command. For some reason it is not working. I believe it is due the fact that the xargs take the arguments one big line of string or when the input is split there is some whitespace, \n or null character.

`ls | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 grep '\d{11}-\d\.(?:json|pdf)'`

if I try just this `ls | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 grep '\d'` It selects file names with digits in them, as soon as I specify the multiplicity regex, nothing matches.

Comment: are you planning to filter the list of _filenames_, or the _contents_ of the files? Because running `... |xargs grep $pattern` would run `grep $pattern file1 file2 ...`, and look at the contents of the files

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. Do you just want to list the filenames? What are some examples of filename that you want to list and that you don't want to list?

Comment: You also don't want to parse the output of `ls`. You haven't clarified what the objective is, but if you are starting with wanting to find files that match a certain pattern(s), you are better off using something along the lines of `find /path/to/directory -type f -name *:json -o -name *pdf`

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes. That would work as well. More clarity is needed on what is expected though.

Comment: @ilkkachu No, I am not looking inside the files, but rather on the filename. I am trying to apply the pattern on the filenames and filtering it.

Comment: @NasirRiley I am trying to filter the file names based on the pattern matches.

Comment: I have edited the question and made it more clear. I am not sure why, it was also showing the matched file names with just `\d` on the command as regex. Does it look inside file and filenames ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, `ls | xargs grep 'pattern'` makes grep look for occurrences in
contents of files listed by `ls`, not in list of filenames. To look for
filenames it should be enough to do:

```
ls | grep 'pattern'
```

Second, `grep '\d{11}-\d\.(?:json|pdf)'` would work only with GNU grep
and -P option. Use the following syntax instead - it works with GNU,
busybox and FreeBSD implementations of grep:

```
ls | grep -E '[[:digit:]]{11}-[[:digit:]]\.(json|pdf)'
```

Third, [parsing ls is not a good
idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). Use
`GNU find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep -regex '.*/[[:digit:]]{11}-[[:digit:]]\.(json|pdf)'
```

or FreeBSD find:

```
find -E . -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*/[[:digit:]]{11}-[[:digit:]]\.(json|pdf)'
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. The one I was missing; the -P option.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any of that complexity. Just use a shell glob. This one is for shells such as `bash` that understand `{x,y}` braced alternatives:

```
ls *[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9].{json,pdf}
```

If you want to do something with the matched files, don't take the output of `ls` but just use the glob to iterate across the files directly.

Comment: that is a lot of digit regex :). I was looking for a more consistent regex based solution as the directory has a lot of files. Thanks for you reply.

Comment: It's not a regex; it's a glob used directly by the shell. Try it